# Which one is right one in pipelining?

Tags: cpu, pipeline, gantt-chart

I'm studying CPU pipelining, and had a trouble.
I want to know which one is right pipelining in below picture
In my opinion, the first Gantt chart is kinda "structural hazard" becuase "IF" stage is partially overlapped. I think that using one stage for two instruction is not allowed. So I think that second one is right....
 Am i right?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

The first chart has two instructions being fetched during the second cycle.  Unless specified otherwise, this cannot be done.

There are circumstances in which this is allowable:

- The instruction fetch is divided into two stages, `IF1` and `IF2`, each of which take 1 cycle.  `IF1` and `IF2` can be overlapped.
- The data path and instruction cache support 2 simultaneous operations.